# This code to sort array can sort only one value, Why?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I wrote this code to sort an one dimension array but when I run this code , the black form show to me only minimum number in index 0 in second array...
this is my code :

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class anything1 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // inserting array
        int[] RandomArray = { 9, 5, 2, 3, 4, 22, 10, 8 };

        // sorting array
        int[] Sortedarray = new int[RandomArray.length];
        int count = 0;
        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < RandomArray.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < RandomArray.length; j++) {
                if (i != j & RandomArray[i] != 0) {
                    if (RandomArray[i] < RandomArray[j]) {
                        Sortedarray[count] = RandomArray[i];
                        x = i;
                    } else {
                        Sortedarray[count] = RandomArray[j];
                        i = j;
                        x = j;
                    }
                }
            }
            RandomArray[x] = 0;
            i = count;
            count = count + 1;
            System.out.println("Count is : " + count);

            // break;
        }

        // write random array

        for (int n = 0; n < RandomArray.length; n++) {
            System.out.println("This is new random array:" + RandomArray[n]);
        }

        // write sorted array

        for (int z = 0; z < Sortedarray.length; z++) {
            System.out.println("This is sorted array:" + Sortedarray[z]);
        }
    }
}
```

this is photo of result the result , any  other value else index 0 is 0 I want to know how do I can to put he next min number in index 1 then the next min number in index 2 ...

http://im55.gulfup.com/giGcht.png

Comment: Your if header `if (i != j & RandomArray[i] != 0) ` needs two `&`, not just one.

Comment: @ChrisTarazi that won't solve the problem, it will only convert it into a short-circuit operator.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Probably why it was only a comment and not an answer.

Comment: How does this sort things? Also, why are you overwriting your source array? `RandomArray[x] = 0;`

Comment: Not that it solves anything but start using proper indentation (I edited your code a little to make it more readable). This will make your code cleaner and will help you for instance see scope of variables or where code blocks actually start or end (misplaced `{` or `}` can cause few annoying problems).

Comment: Are you trying to implement a selection sort?

Comment: Never assign to a loop counter (`i = j`, `i = count`) unless you really know what you're doing (but then you wouldn't do it anyway).

Comment: I guess the problem is here: `i != j & RandomArray[i] != 0`, it should be `i != j & RandomArray[j] != 0`.

Comment: @Arsham looks like it. And should be using a different approach.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza that change alone doesn't fix the problem, it only causes even more overwriting of his source array

Comment: @KevinL it was a shot in the dark, and helped me to have a better understanding of what algorithm OP is trying to implement, which is a selection sort (in a very odd way, though).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Just a simple web search and he can find the answer to his question. He needs to move the else part outside of the inner loop and implement it correctly so it swaps the elements ( I think that is what he is trying to do in the else section of his if statement)

Comment: @Arsham I guess OP can use a way simpler implementation for the algorithm, but I find interesting how to accomplish it from the current given code aside that the common implementations you can find out there.

Comment: Show us a full printout of your display when you run this. Specifically I want to see the lines that show count is increasing.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather swap values directly in the array than making a new array. Your problem is that you define values in your `SortedArray` for every `j` loop passage. Something like this can be  used :

```
    int [] randomArray = {9,5,2,3,4,22,10,8};
    int swap;

    for(int i=0; i<randomArray.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<randomArray.length; j++){
            if(i != j && randomArray[i] > randomArray[j]){
                swap = randomArray[i];
                randomArray[i] = randomArray[j];
                randomArray[j] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
```

If you really need to have a second array, you can copy your original one and use the copy.